# How to share mutliprocessing queue object between multiple computers

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue

I followed the doc on Python's [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). There is an example on how to use `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` to share the same `Queue` between the multiple machines. The server example is pretty simple:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import Queue
queue = Queue.Queue()
class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
QueueManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda:queue)
m = QueueManager(address=('0.0.0.0', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

The client is even simpler:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
QueueManager.register('get_queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
m.connect()
queue = m.get_queue()
queue.put('hello')
```

The problem is that the client can't connect to server. What needs to be changed in order to establish communication between the client and server?

Comment: Are your server and client on different computers?

Comment: Testing using the same machine.

Comment: Your code works in my recent Arch Linux environment. what OS are you using ? do you get any error message ? how did you confirmed that "client can't connect to server?"

Comment: Running it on OS X. The client is hanging while executing the `m.connect()` statement on a line # 5.

Comment: confirmed that it works in Mac OS environment. before running the client, check that server process is really listening on 50000 port using `lsof -i tcp:50000`.  Also check that localhost has ipv4 address `127.0.0.1` using `host localhost`. if not, maybe changing `localhost` in server code to `127.0.0.1` will help.