# Python multiprocessing possible deadlock with two queue as producer-consumer pattern?

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing, deadlock

I'm wondering if there can be a sort of deadlock in the following code. I have to read each element of a database (about 1 million items), process it, then collect the results in a unique file.

I've parallelized the execution with **multiprocessing** using two Queue's and three types of processes:

- **Reader**: Main process which reads the database and adds the read items in a task_queue
- **Worker**: Pool of processes. Each worker gets an item from task_queue, processes the item, saves the results in an intermediate file stored in item_name/item_name.txt and puts the item_name in a completed_queue
- **Writer**: Process which gets an item_name from completed_queue, gets the intermediate result from item_name/item_name.txt and writes it in results.txt

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue
class Computation():

    def __init__(self,K):
        self.task_queue = Queue()
        self.completed_queue = Queue()
        self.n_cpus = K

    def reader(self,):
        with open(db, "r") as db:
            ... # Read an item
            self.task_queue.put(item)
            
    def worker(self,):
        while True:
            item = self.task_queue.get(True)
            if item == "STOP":
                break
            self.process_item(item)

    def writer_process(self,):
        while True:
            f = self.completed_queue.get(True)
            if f == "DONE":
               break
            self.write_f(f)

    def run(self,):
        pool = Pool(n_cpus, self.worker, args=())
        
        writer = Process(target=self.writer_process, args=())
        writer.start()

        self.reader()

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        self.completed_queue.put("DONE")
        writer.join()
```

The code works, but it seems that sometimes the writer or the pool stops working (or they are very slow). Is a deadlock possible in this scenario?

Comment: Difficult to say. Are the workers writing to different intermediate files? Otherwise you could have a data race.

Comment: @jinatius Yes, they write on different files. The workers's jobs are independent since each item_name is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First, by using the queues as you are, you are in effect creating your own process pool and have no need for using the `multiprocessing.Pool` class at all. You are using a pool initializer as an actual pool worker and it's a bit of a misuse of this class; you would be better off to just use regular `Process` instances (my opinion, anyway).

Second, although it is well and good that you are putting message `DONE` to the `writer_process` to signal it to terminate, you have not done similarly for the `self.n_cpus` `worker` processes, which are looking for 'STOP' messages, and therefore the `reader` function needs to put `self.n_cpus` `STOP` messages in the task queue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class Computation():

    def __init__(self, K):
        self.task_queue = Queue()
        self.completed_queue = Queue()
        self.n_cpus = K

    def reader(self,):
        with open(db, "r") as db:
            ... # Read an item
            self.task_queue.put(item)
        # signal to the worker processes to terminate:
        for _ in range(self.n_cpus):
            self.task_queue.put('STOP')
            
    def worker(self,):
        while True:
            item = self.task_queue.get(True)
            if item == "STOP":
                break
            self.process_item(item)

    def writer_process(self,):
        while True:
            f = self.completed_queue.get(True)
            if f == "DONE":
               break
            self.write_f(f)

    def run(self):
        processes = [Process(target=self.worker) for _ in range(self.n_cpus)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        
        writer = Process(target=self.writer_process, args=())
        writer.start()

        self.reader()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        self.completed_queue.put("DONE")
        writer.join()
```

Personally, instead of using 'STOP' and 'DONE' as the *sentinel* messages, I would use `None` instead, assuming that is not a valid actual message. I have tested the above code where `reader` just processed strings in a list and `self.process_item(item)` simply appended ' done' to the each of those strings and put the modified string on the `completed_queue` and replaced `self.write_f` in the `writer_process` with a `print` call. I did not see any problems with the code as is.

**Update to use a Managed Queue**

**Disclaimer:** I have had no experience using mpi4py and have no idea how the queue proxies would get distributed across different computers. The above code *may* not be sufficient as suggested by the following article, [How to share mutliprocessing queue object between multiple computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086774/how-to-share-mutliprocessing-queue-object-between-multiple-computers). **However, that code is creating instances of Queue.Queue (that code is Python 2 code) and *not* the proxies that are returned by the multiprocessing.SyncManager.** *The documentation on this is very poor.* Try the above change to see if it works better (it will be slower).

Because the proxy returned by `manager.Queue()`, I have had to rearrange the code a bit; the queues are now being passed explicitly as arguments to the process functions:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


class Computation():

    def __init__(self, K):
        self.n_cpus = K

    def reader(self, task_queue):
        with open(db, "r") as db:
            ... # Read an item
        # signal to the worker processes to terminate:
        for _ in range(self.n_cpus):
            task_queue.put('STOP')

    def worker(self, task_queue, completed_queue):
        while True:
            item = task_queue.get(True)
            if item == "STOP":
                break
            self.process_item(item)

    def writer_process(self, completed_queue):
        while True:
            f = completed_queue.get(True)
            if f == "DONE":
               break
            self.write_f(f)

    def run(self):
        with Manager() as manager:
            task_queue = manager.Queue()
            completed_queue = manager.Queue()
            processes = [Process(target=self.worker, args=(task_queue, completed_queue)) for _ in range(self.n_cpus)]
            for p in processes:
                p.start()

            writer = Process(target=self.writer_process, args=(completed_queue,))
            writer.start()

            self.reader(task_queue)

            for p in processes:
                p.join()

            completed_queue.put("DONE")
            writer.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the "STOP" messages were a sort of typo, I forgot to insert them when I formulate this question, but there are in the real code in the same position as you mention. Regarding the Pool, thanks it's better in that way. In general, my project works on a cluster and this code is executed on different nodes of the cluster: to manage different nodes I use MPI (mpi4py) and each node is in charge to process a different part of the dataset. Could the interaction between mpi4py and multiprocessing generate some problem?

Comment: Mentioning only now that the queue needs to be shared across different computers is a bit of a game changer. For this I believe you need to create a `multiprocessing.Manager` instance instance (let's call it `manager`) and then, for example, `self.task_queue = manager.Queue()`. Maybe that's the only change you need depending on how things are distributed or it can be very complicated. I will update the answer to make this clearer.